# Why is it a problem for the others that Mike was not at Harvard

Tags: plot-explanation, suits

Mike is sued for fraud, but even that is not completely proven, since the jury would have voted not guilty.

1. Why could Harvey, Louis & Jessica being sued for? For "KNOWING" the
   fact? Unless there is a written letter stating "I know (at date) of
   the fact" how could anybody have a problem? It is not possible to
   prove they knew it and other than the fact that their reputation is
   damaged (but even if the attorney couldnt prove it - how should they
   be any better)
2. Wouldnt it be a much bigger problem for his friend when he accepts
   the deal, because he lied at court and when Mike took the deal and
   with that, he officially proved it to be a lie (or is it possible to
   say: yes, I a did not go to harvard, but my friend didnt lie when he
   said otherwise)

Answer (score 1):

> Mike is sued for fraud

No, actually, he was tried for "Conspiracy to commit fraud".

Mike had not graduated law school or have a licence (AFAIK) to practice law and every time he appeared in court and called himself a lawyer would have been a fraud.

However, the issue here is **"Conspiracy"** which means he conspired to act illegally and that he actually did.

Harvey **knew** Mike was not a lawyer but allowed him to present himself as one and then involved Jessica and Louis by telling them.

The *first* thing they should have done was expose Mike and by not doing so they exposed their clients to potential harm if Mike had operate as a lawyer for the,

Additionally, their clients could have sued *them* for misrepresentation 7/or malpractice.

> It is not possible to prove they knew it

Possibly but that's what the trial would have covered but Mike took the plea before the rest of the firm could be involved and possibly destroyed.